# Client side timer for session in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, session, timer

We have an MVC application that has a session time out.  Somewhere I am assuming that the session time is being tracked.

I need to show on the client side, a visual timer.

I have looked at examples using jQuery but those are mainly client side only with not communication with the application timer.

What is the best approach to get the session time to the client side to show a visual representation of the session timer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you contact the server, it gets reset so what's the goal?

Comment: The server may not actually get contacted. If the user sits on something like a checkout page for more than 20 minutes, then their session will have already expired when they finally submit. That could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, your timer *has* to be client-side. @SteveGreene is right in the respect that if you contact the server, the session timeout will be reset, so if you were to long poll to find the current remaining time from the server, it would effectively always be the same, as each request to get the time would reset the timeout.

You just have to know the timeout, and then set a client-side timer based on that. For example, the default timeout is 20 minutes, so client-side you'd just create a timer at page load 20 minutes long. If nothing is done to reset the timeout, then when the client-side timer expires the session will have timed out as well.

Comment: The issue is that the timeout would be site wide, not based on an action or DOM reload.  Meaning that the customer has 20 minutes to finalize a full transaction.  This means while they are jumping around our site.    I can see how to trigger the session timeout event to the controller action using an action result call, but I need to keep the timer at the last interval if they leave the page.  Would a cookie work?  I don't know if cookies can get that granular in time stamping.

Comment: You're conflating two different things. The session timeout is sliding, not absolute. If the user navigates around the site, they reset the timeout with each request. In other words, if they are actively using the site, the timeout will never occur. If you need to ensure that some action must be taken within 20 minutes, then you must track that on your own.